# ALL operator VS Any on an empty query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm reading the [oracle documentation](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql.php) on the ANY and ALL operators. I pretty understand their uses except for one thing. It states:

ALL :

> If a subquery returns zero rows, the condition evaluates to TRUE.

ANY :

> If a subquery returns zero rows, the condition evaluates to FALSE.

It doesn't seem very logical to me. Why would ALL on an empty subquery would return TRUE but ANY returns FALSE?

I'm relatively new to SQL, so I assume it would have a use-case for this behavior which is really counter-intuitive to me.

ANY and ALL on an empty set should return the same value no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `ANY` is to be interpreted as `EXIST` (if there is any, it means they exist). Therefore, it return false if no rows are found.

`All` does not certify that any values exist, it just certifies that it represents all possible values. Therefore, it return true even if no rows are found.

Comment: It worth to mention an example: If you have a check to do like `empSalary > ALL (select salary from someTable)` if there is no rows on `select salary from someTable` it evaluate to true because the value you are checking IS bigger then ´all the values (even if they doesn't exist)´ :)

Answer (score 13):

Consider the example of the `EMP` table in that link.

Specifically this query -

```
SELECT e1.empno, e1.sal
FROM   emp e1
WHERE  e1.sal > ANY (SELECT e2.sal
                     FROM   emp e2
                     WHERE  e2.deptno = 20);
```

In case of ANY, the question you are asking is "Is my salary greater than anyone in department 20 (at least 1 person)". This means you are hoping **at least one** person has a salary less than you. When there are no rows, this returns `FALSE` because there is nobody whose salary is less than you, you were hoping for at least one.

In case of ALL, the obvious question you would be asking is "Is my salary greater than everyone?". Rephrasing that as "Is there nobody that has salary greater than me?" When there are no rows returned, your answer is `TRUE`, because "there is indeed nobody whose salary is greater than me.

Comment: should be the best answer