# EXISTS vs ALL, ANY, SOME

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-algebra

I'm trying to understand the difference between EXISTS and ALL in MySQL. Let me give you an example:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
           FROM table2
          WHERE table2.val < table1.val
       );

SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE val <= ALL( SELECT val FROM table2 );
```

A quote from MySQL docs:

> Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it could
>   begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. MySQL
>   ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference. [[1]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Reading this, it seems to me that mysql should be able to translate both queries to the same relational algebra expression. Both queries are just a simple comparison between values from two tables. However, that doesn't seem to be the case. I tried both queries and the second one performs much better than the first one.

- How are this queries exactly handled by the optimizer?
- Why the optimizer can't make the first query perform as the second one?
- Is it always more efficient to use an ALL/ANY/SOME condition?

Comment: What about NULL values?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946163/all-operator-vs-any-on-an-empty-query/28946336#28946336. As for some, it does the same thing as ANY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries in your question are not equivalent, so they will have different execution plans regardless of how well they're optimized. If you used `NOT val > ANY(...)` then it would be equivalent.

You should always use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan of a query and realize that the execution plan can change as your data changes. Testing and understanding the execution plan will help you determine which methods perform better. There is no hard and fast rule for ALL/ANY/SOME and they're often optimized down to an EXISTS.